# ConTeXt lettermodule backaddress

Tags: context, letters

I have been using the context letter module and am trying to remove the backaddress but I am having difficulty

```
\usemodule[letter]

\setupletterstyle[backaddress=no] % trying to switch off backaddress

\setupletter
    [fromname={The Author},
     fromaddress={Hidden Street 2\\57895 Mystery town}]

\setupletter
    [toname={Mike Wilson},
     toaddress={Linden street 12\\78569 TeX City}]


\startletter
    [opening={Dear Reader,},
     subject={Step by step guide to write a letter},
     closing={Greetings from the Author}]

    Thus, I came to the conclusion ...

\stopletter
```

Is not working. Neither is

```
\setupletterstyle[backaddress][alternative=no]
```

The last manual is from 2010. Did something change in the meantime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things have changed internally and the documentation has not been updated.  Mainly, the `\setupletterstyle` command has been replace by `\setupletterlayer`.  Just for reference, those are the manuals available:

- [correspondence.pdf](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/correspondence/downloads/correspondence.pdf) User manual with examples.
- [commands.pdf](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/correspondence/downloads/commands.pdf) Command reference which lists all the possible keys.

Whenever I use the correspondence module I usually just browse the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/wolfs/correspondence/src) to find how to modify things.  Admittedly that is maybe not the best way for a non-power user.

```
\usemodule[letter]

\setupletter
    [fromname={The Author},
     fromaddress={Hidden Street 2\\57895 Mystery town}]

\setupletter
    [toname={Mike Wilson},
     toaddress={Linden street 12\\78569 TeX City}]

\setupletterlayer
    [backaddress]
    [state=stop]

\startletter
    [opening={Dear Reader,},
     subject={Step by step guide to write a letter},
     closing={Greetings from the Author}]

    Thus, I came to the conclusion ...

\stopletter
```

Comment: Thanks Henri. It's a very nice module shame that the manual is outdated. I was able to manage by looking at the source code, but it is a bit of a puzzle. BTW: in the files folder there are some test files that contain some good examples of the updated interface